# How to loop a menu if wrong selection occurred

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, menu, program-entry-point

I am trying to loop a menu when the user insert wrong choice:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner YourChoice = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("+-------------------------+");
    System.out.println("|        Welcome          |");
    System.out.println("|    To this program      |");
    System.out.println("+-------------------------+");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Please Choose your preference: ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Press 1 - Test1");
    System.out.println("Press 2 - Test2");
    System.out.println("Press 3 - Test3");
    System.out.println("Press 0 - Exit");


    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Your Choice is: ");
    int CHOICE = YourChoice.nextInt();



    if (CHOICE == 1) {
        System.out.println("You want Test1"); 
    }
    else if (CHOICE == 2) {
        System.out.println("You want Test2"); 
    }
    else if (CHOICE == 3) {
        System.out.println("You want Test3"); 
    }
    else if (CHOICE == 0) {
        System.out.println("You want Exit"); 
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Wrong Input, please try again");

    }
```

What I want is, if a user inserted wrong number, then the menu should start again, until the user enters a correct value (0 to 3). 
I am not sure where and how to put the while loop,
Could you please clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use only `while` and `switch-case` in your program.

You can try the below code. It runs successfully.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("+-------------------------+");
        System.out.println("|        Welcome          |");
        System.out.println("|    To this program      |");
        System.out.println("+-------------------------+");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner yourChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice ; 
        boolean tryAgain = true;

        while (tryAgain){

            System.out.println("Please Choose your preference: ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Press 1 - Test1");
            System.out.println("Press 2 - Test2");
            System.out.println("Press 3 - Test3");
            System.out.println("Press 0 - Exit");
            System.out.println();
            choice = yourChoice.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\nYour Choice is : " +choice + "\n");

            switch(choice){
                case 1 :
                    System.out.println("You want Test1");
                    tryAgain = false;
                    break;
                case 2 :
                    System.out.println("You want Test2");
                    tryAgain = false;
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    System.out.println("You want Test3");
                    tryAgain = false;
                    break;
                case 0 :
                    System.out.println("You want exit");
                    tryAgain = false;
                    break;
                default :
                    System.out.println("Wrong Input, please try again");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same code as mine, why post another answer with the same code?

Comment: @Pluto Sorry. Its not same code as yours. There are differences. Please check once. Also when I posted the answer first time I dint see yours.. may be we have posted in a similar time. As I executed it first and then posted the answer.

Comment: @MohammedHashim : Welcome Bro ! If you can please accept my answer, if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use with `switch case` , its good for the code efficiency , to use with alot of `if` and `else if` its not so good :

```
Scanner YourChoice = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("+-------------------------+");
            System.out.println("|        Welcome          |");
            System.out.println("|    To this program      |");
            System.out.println("+-------------------------+");
            System.out.println();

            boolean flag = false;

            do {
                System.out.println("Please Choose your preference: ");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Press 1 - Test1");
                System.out.println("Press 2 - Test2");
                System.out.println("Press 3 - Test3");
                System.out.println("Press 0 - Exit");

                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("Your Choice is: ");
                int CHOICE = YourChoice.nextInt();

                switch (CHOICE) {
                case 0: {
                    System.out.println("You want Exit");
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                case 1: {
                    System.out.println("You want Test1");
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    System.out.println("You want Test2");
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                case 3: {
                    System.out.println("You want Test3");
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                default:{
                    System.out.println("Wrong Input, please try again");
                    break;
                    }
                }

            } while (!flag);
}
}
```

Comment: Lots of unnecessary braces in case statements. Those are not required.

Answer (score -1):

public static void main(String[] args)
    {

```
int CHOICE;
Scanner YourChoice = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("+-------------------------+");
System.out.println("|        Welcome          |");
System.out.println("|    To this program      |");
System.out.println("+-------------------------+");
System.out.println();
while(true)
{
   System.out.println("Please Choose your preference: ");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Press 1 - Test1");
   System.out.println("Press 2 - Test2");
   System.out.println("Press 3 - Test3");
   System.out.println("Press 0 - Exit");


   System.out.println();
   System.out.print("Your Choice is: ");
   CHOICE = YourChoice.nextInt();

   if (CHOICE == 1)
   {
      System.out.println("You want Test1"); 
   }
   else if (CHOICE == 2) 
   {
      System.out.println("You want Test2"); 
   }
   else if (CHOICE == 3) 
   {
      System.out.println("You want Test3"); 
   }
   else if (CHOICE == 0) 
   {
      System.out.println("You want Exit"); 
      System.exit(0);
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.println("Wrong Input, please try again");

   }
```

}
 }

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked except you forgot to type break; at 1 to 3, otherwise, the menu was getting repeated even when you type 1, 2, or 3

Comment: No no that's why I didn't use (break) because I've to repeat the menu because if user want to do another thing so it is useful to repeat the loop rather than starting again and again. (Sometimes it is very useful to repeat the loop, you'll understand when you make another programs of this type).